# How generate keys pair in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

i wanna create function to generate keys pair

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
contract Test {
  function generateKeys() public view returns (uint256 privateKey, uint256 publicKey) {
    bytes32 seed = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(blockhash(block.number - 1), msg.sender));
    privateKey = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked("TEST BLAH BLAH", seed)));
    publicKey = ECDSA.publicKey(privateKey);
    return (privateKey, publicKey);
  }
}
```

but i have an error `generateKeys not found`
What can i use instead of `ECDSA.publicKey` ?

Comment: 1) "generateKeys not found" seems like an issue related to some other code that tries to execute this contract. Can you edit the question and post the other code (possibly JS or Python or other language) as well? ... 2) "ECDSA.publicKey" - there's no function in the OpenZeppelin ECDSA library that would generate a public key from a private key. Since all data (including runtime data) is public on most EVM networks, it's generally discouraged to generate private keys (and other data that should not be public) in contracts. Can you describe your use case? Maybe there's a better workaround.